# An example of isomorphic groups from the real life that is hard to notice.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, applications, group-isomorphism

Give me please an example of the isomorphic groups from the real life that is hard to notice. I mean two groups that are actually isomorphic and exist near us, but if we consider them briefly it will be almost impossible to notice an isomorphism or some kind of similiarity between them.

*For example the movements of someone is a set and a composition law is applying them during some interval of time. It is associative because once I decided what movements I am going to make it does not matter for the outcome from which one I will begin. The identity element is not moving at all. And a reverse element is to move to the previous position.*

Comment: $$\Bbb R^2_{\Bbb R}\cong\Bbb C_{\Bbb R}$$ though "real life" can be tough to get in mathematics...

Comment: How do you define "groups from real life"? A group is an abstract concept, so how would that be visible in real life? What you can see in real life are mostly group actions, but if we try to figure out the group hiding behind it, it already gets theoretical...

Comment: abstract group vs. group of transformations

Comment: For example the movements of someone is a set and a composition law is applying them during some interval of time. It is associative because once I decided what movements I am going to make it does not matter for the outcome from which one I will begin. The identity element is not moving at all. And a reverse element is to move to the previous position.

Comment: @Bemte, I define groups from the real life just in the same way we do it for an abstract concepts.

Comment: Like some of the other comments are getting at, it's not quite clear what the question means. Here's one possible answer: Icosahedra/dodecahedra are familiar enough in "real life" that nonmathematicians can often recognize them. The oriented symmetry group of either of these shapes is isomorphic to the set of shuffles of a five-card deck that are given by swapping pairs of cards and even number of time. Both of these groups are isomorphic to the alternating group $A_5$ on five elements (almost by definition in the latter case).

Comment: After reading the edit I doubt that this question as posed is actually about mathematics, or at best it's not well-defined.

Comment: @Travis, oh yeah! Your example is pretty good, but I think it is possible that there are exist even more hidden example of group isomorphism in real life.

Comment: $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R_+^*},\times)$  isomorphic using $\exp$ function.